# Get description from active directory

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, active-directory

I'm working on importing groups and users from active directory using sql server.  I've found the following code to pull both the groups and the users.

```
CREATE TABLE ##Groups ( CN VARCHAR(128), DN VARCHAR(1024), Email VARCHAR(128), ADSPath VARCHAR(1024));
CREATE TABLE ##Users ( DistributionGroup VARCHAR(128), FirstName VARCHAR(50), LastName VARCHAR(50), EmailAddress VARCHAR(128));

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(1024)

SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO ##Groups (CN, DN, Email, ADSPath) SELECT CN, distinguishedName DN, mail Email, ADSPath FROM OpenQuery(ADSI, ''<LDAP://controller.domain.com:389/DC=domain,DC=com>;(&(objectClass=Group));cn, distinguishedName, mail, ADSPath;subtree'') ORDER BY distinguishedName';
EXEC(@sql);

DECLARE @CN VARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @DN VARCHAR(1024)

SELECT TOP 1 @CN = CN, @DN = DN FROM ##Groups

WHILE EXISTS(SELECT DN FROM ##Groups WHERE DN > @DN)
BEGIN

      SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO ##Users (DistributionGroup, Firstname, LastName, EmailAddress) SELECT '''+@CN+''' [Distribution Group], ISNULL(givenName, '''') FirstName, ISNULL(sn, '''') LastName, mail EmailAddress FROM OpenQuery(ADSI, ''<LDAP://controller.domain.com:389/DC=domain,DC=com>;(&(objectClass=User)(memberOf='+@DN+'));givenName, sn, mail;subtree'')'; 
      EXEC(@sql)

      SELECT TOP 1 @CN = CN, @DN = DN FROM ##Groups WHERE DN > @DN
END

SELECT * FROM ##Groups;
SELECT * FROM ##Users;

DROP TABLE ##Groups;
DROP TABLE ##Users;
```

That works pretty nicely.  Now, i'd like to pull out the description for the groups, but i can't seem to find out what the field is called.  help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The description for groups in AD is stored in the **description** attribute.

Reference: [Microsoft AD Schema Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675492(v=vs.85).aspx)

**EDIT:** It seems that you can't actually pull the description attribute in using ADSI Linked Server in SQL because it is a multi-valued attribute. For an alternative way of pulling data from AD for import into SQL server, see [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885337/active-directory-data-into-sql-table/4996626#4996626).

Comment: ok.  i add description to the query and get this error: Msg 7341, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot get the current row value of column "[ADSDSOObject].description" from OLE DB provider "ADSDSOObject" for linked server "ADSI". Could not convert the data value due to reasons other than sign mismatch or overflow.

Comment: @DForck42: you probably can't get it through the crippled OLE DB provider since `description` is a potentially multi-valued attribute. I don't think there's anything you can do about that, unfortunately....

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/7026e0b3-c20d-4e19-a017-926a23df60d7/