# Wso2 Userstore migration from LDAP to DB (Custom user store)

Tags: wso2-identity-server

We are using WSO2 identity server with LDAP as a user store. Now we would like to replace LDAP with database because of huge load (> 10 Millions) and growing. I have migrated the users but how tenant details in wso2 core database could be set with the new user store. That is the user store xml details are stored in their tenant table. How this could be migrated. Or what are all the changes, configurations, needs to be set in wso2 identity server level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment we don't have exact mechanism to migrate data from one DB type to another. What we have is upgrading one version to another using same DB.

But you can do this migrating data from an LDAP to any DB like MySQL manually. If you can write an shell script to  convert LDAP data toa csv file, its easy for you  to move to a MySQL like DB in one import command.

Furthermore, I was able to find out some similar articles which can help you to migrate content from LDAP to MySQL [2],[3],[4]

- The table structures of DB types can be found from [1].
- Once you  migrate the data to JDBC, you can change the custom-userstore.xml file with new connection values and restart the server. If you changed your primary user store, you need to change the user store configurations in user-mgt.xml file.

Please let me know if you need further help in migrating.

[1]https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS550/Data+Dictionary
[2] https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/dfae020f-a3bf-4e9b-9614-eccf7890f8c6/how-to-extract-data-from-ldap-and-then-import-it-into-sql-database-for-quicker-retrieval?forum=transactsql
[3][Active Directory data into SQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885337/active-directory-data-into-sql-table)
[4] https://www.egnyte.com/blog/2014/01/how-we-migrated-millions-of-users-from-ldap-to-mysql-using-feature-flags/

Comment: i have tried the above process already and got successful results. Partially you have answered my question. But the tenant information (xml) is stored as blob in wso2 tenant table which contains which tenant uses which user store (LDAP / DB....) right now all our tenants xml contains LDAP (ReadWriteLDAPuserStoreManager) but in my case i have successfully migrated the users of all our users but these xml configurations i couldn't only manually getting and modifying only possible i think please correct me i am wrong in this.

Comment: If you have few secondary user stores in tenants, the best ways are to first migrate the LDAP user store separately to a JDBC database manually. Next in the userstore.xml of the tenant can be manually updated or you can re-create the JDBC secondary user store for that tenant with the same name after deleting the existing user store, pointing to the newly migrated database.